# How to set number of lines in table view headers for grouped style

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to set the number of lines for the table view header text for the grouped style?

By default, iOS will show all the lines of text in the header for grouped style. I want the text to ellipse after two lines similar to setting the number of lines to `2` on `textLabel` or `detailLabel` of a table view cell.

I know I could do this through a custom table view header view but I'm wondering if I can set the max number of lines without having to create a custom view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set the number of lines for the table view header text for the grouped style?

If you are using the dataSource method `titleForHeaderInSection`, then obviously the answer is **NO**, since it only asks for `String?` value. I reckon there's no way to do it. However, there's a "hack" for that, of course, use the... as we all know: **new line character `\n`** for multi-lines, and do similar dirty method for the ellipsis thing.

---

> I know I could do this through a custom table view header view...

This is the better way^. `viewForHeaderInSection`.